# Starting plugin Data Plotly

Tags: qgis-plugins, plot, dataplotly

I'm using QGIS Desktop 3.10.3 with GRASS 7.8.2

I tried to run the plugin "Data Plotly"
https://anitagraser.com/2017/12/06/data-exploration-with-data-plotly-for-qgis3/

After installing the plugin I get the following message:

[image: Error QgsProcessingAlgorithm.createInstance() is abstract and must be overridden]

[image]
I already tried to reinstall the plugin and install also an older QGIS Version but still can't run the plugin.

Unfortunately, my scripting skills are not enough to fix the problem on my own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems odd, but based on the error message, it would appear that the problem is caused because the `createInstance()` method is not re-implemented in the plugin processing script.

**Disclaimer:** I have not tested this so I cannot guarantee that this will fix the problem, but if you want to try to hack the code in your plugin installation, you could *try* the following:

Locate the file `dataplotly_algorithms.py` in the `processing` folder inside the plugin file structure, and edit it to add the following method inside the `DataPlotlyProcessingPlot` class:

```py
def createInstance(self):
    return type(self)()
```

For the sake of simplicity, you can add it directly above the `initAlgorithm()` method. Make sure that the indentation matches the rest of the class methods.